# Possible causes of a malfunctioning database saving function

Tags: c#, mysql, thread-safety

I have a class similar to the following code, which needs to be thread safe. It is simply a function which saves/maps a class instance in to a database row.

If the `ID` property of the class instance is 0, it is considered to be a new item - in this situation a blank row is inserted and its auto increment value/row id is returned. Following this the row is `UPDATE`d, using the returned auto increment value in the `WHERE` clause.

If the `ID` property is greater than 0, the method only uses the `UPDATE` query.

The problem I'm experiencing is occasionally/'randomly', either empty rows or duplicate rows will be created. I'm struggling to determine the cause and cannot reproduce it reliably in a way I can easily diagnose.

It has all the signs of a race condition to me, but I can't see why that would happen - especially given the `lock` surrounding the guts of the method:

Can anyone spot the problem in this class/method, or does my problem lie elsewhere?

```
public class clsItem
{
    static clsDatabase DB;
    static string TableName = "myTable";
            static readonly object syncLock = new Object();
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public string Description; 

    public bool Save()
    {
        lock(syncLock) {
        if (ID < 0 || !(DB.ServerAvailable && DB.CredentialsAuthenticated)) return false;
        bool newItem = (ID == 0) ? true : false;

        long InsertID = 0;

        if (newItem) // make blank row and return ID
        {
            if (DB.Query("INSERT INTO " + TableName + " values()", ref InsertID) == null || InsertID == 0) return false;
            ID = (int)InsertID;
        }
        List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        FieldInfo[] props = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (FieldInfo pi in props)
        {
            if (newItem && pi.Name == "ID")
                parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(pi.Name, InsertID));
            else
                parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(this)));
        }
        string query = "UPDATE " + TableName + " SET name = @Name, desc = @Description WHERE id = @ID";
        return (DB.Query(query, parameters) == null) ? false : true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Within the block protected by the lock you access ID multiple times. Are all other places where its value is set also protected by a lock on syncLock? Same issue could exist for other fields accessed with the block.

Comment: Remember, the purpose of lock is to control access to shared resources, not just serialize entry into a particular chunk of code.

Comment: @hatchet the ID is only ever changed either by this save function (if it is a new row/item), or in the Load() method of the class (should I protect this with the same syncLock?). As this is not a static class I can't see how this would cause a conflicting situation as the instance only ever has its ID set once

Comment: When I see that ID is a public field, that raises the possibility that it could be changed from anywhere, at any time, and if that happened while Save was executing, that would be a problem. But without seeing the larger context of how this class is being used, I can only point to it as a potential problem. It might help if you describe why you thought the lock was needed in the first place, i.e. are multiple threads accessing particular instances of this class.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and I should probably make it a public property with a private setter rather than a field, but it isn't being set elsewhere anyhow. The reason for the lock was mostly a hopeful test to see if it was an issue with the same instance being saved by different threads. Although really, while the instance may be read by other threads, with this particular class each item is only saved once (in a new row situation). I have other classes which follow this pattern though.